# Plotting using highcharts.js labels are being rendered off-center in stead of being centered

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts (highcharts.js) to create a plot using the 'bands' feature. The bands are configured as follows :

```
"plotBands": [{
                "color": "#E5F6F6",
                "from": -0.5,
                "to": 4.5,
                "label": {
                    "text": 'January',
                    "align": "center",
                    "verticalAlign": "top"
                }
            }, {
                "color": "#FFFFFF",
                "from": 3.5,
                "to": 8.5,
                "label": {
                    "text": "February",
                    "align": "center",
                    "verticalAlign": "top"
                }
            }]
```

This config uses align:center on labels, therefore they should be horizontally centered. Unfortunately, they are being rendered off-center.

You can find a fiddle demonstrating the issue here : http://jsfiddle.net/MpvSA/ .

The "January" label should be horizontally centered, but it is displayed more at 65% than at 50%. This problem is reliably reproduced in all browsers I tried.

Any idea why the labels are off-center and how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused because you have two plotbands, white (right) overlap first, because is too wide. (scale to 7, but plotband to 8,5)

So you can set zIndex for first (blue) and problem disappears. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands.zIndex